# IIS Express 8, VS 2012 and 64-bit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t get IIS Express 8 beta to run website as 64-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process)

I have VS 2012 configured with IIS Express 8. I need to run a web site under 64bit process. When I set the platform to x64 in Visual Studio and click Debug, I get an error stating that there is a platform mismatch between the process and DLLs. It appears that my DLLs are correctly compiled as x64, but in the Task Manager, I see that the process is still iisexpress *32.

Why did VS started iisexpress under 32bit? How can I instruct VS to debug into 64-bit version of IISExpress?

Thanks.