# On a 64-bit machine, cannot run the simplest web application when build on x64 platform (use vb in VS)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

My scenario is that, I tried to build a very simple Asp.net web application, actually I did nothing but creating a new  project of web (form) application using VB in visual studio 2012. Then, I changed the configuration to build it on x64 platform, and it always failed. But, if I change back to x86 platform, everything is fine. However, I do need a webapplicaiton built on x64.

When building it, no errors, but these warnings,

---

Rebuild All started: Project: WebApplication_debug, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'WebApplication_debug': Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'WebApplication_debug': Referenced assembly 'System.Data.dll' targets a different processor
vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'WebApplication_debug': Referenced assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.dll' targets a different processor
vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'WebApplication_debug': Referenced assembly 'System.Web.dll' targets a different processor

---

Then, when I run it, I got,

---

Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication_debug, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication_debug, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication_debug, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication_debug, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +86
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +126
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +62
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +307
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

---

I have tried whatever I can, like setup IIS appPool, etc. No work out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to load it in a 32-bit webserver.

Change it to Any CPU so it will load on both architectures.

Comment: SLaks, thank you so much for your input. Yes, I know when I set to "Any CPU", it will work. But, as I mentioned, I like to just use x64 platform, because later on I need to call some Matlab-related dll that is based on 64-bit system. Everything is going well on my 32-bit machine. But, something is going wrong when I move it to 64-bit system. So, I guess I have to get a pure x64 web application work, then I can go ahead to finish the left. For your information, after I change to "Any CPU", build is ok, no error, no warning. run is Ok too. But, when I call some Matlab dll, error shows like bebow

Comment: Line 12: 
Line 13:         Dim out_msg(1) As MWArray
Line 14:         out_msg(0) = New MWCharArray("can you see me in here?")
Line 15: 
Line 16:         'MsgBox(out_msg(0).ToString)

Source File: C:\Users\dongy\Visual_Studio_Projects\WebApplication_debug\WebApplication_debug\call_matlab_net_dll.aspx.vb    Line: 14

Comment: [BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)]
   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR.mclmcrInitialize2(Int32 primaryMode) +0
   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor() +827

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception.]
   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray..cctor() +249

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception.]
   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray..ctor() +0
  ...

Comment: Then make sure your web server is a 64-bit process.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10202047/34397  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3254745-allow-for-iis-express-64-bit-to-run-from-visual-st

Answer (score 0):

If you build it on a 32bit machine, it is likely that you just don't have the 64bit .Net framework installed.

In addition, the built-in Dev server is also 32bit, so you won't be able to run it there.