# MVC Web Service returns - Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am Trying to implement DocX to replace information from documents on a Document Library in Sharepoint using a web service. I am having difficulties because when I run my project and try to send information to the api address I get the following error

```
Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.
```

While debugging the code breaks on the following line

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl))
```

I have found that I need to run the project on 64bit mode but if I choose that option the project does not run. I also found that the option Prefer 32bit cannot be checked but that option is disabled and not checked and finally in the IIS application Pool advance settings I need to turn into true the option Enable 32bit applications but it did not do anything.

None of the earlier have worked for me, I would like to ask for some help on solving this issue.

I am working on Sharepoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012 and MVC 4.

EDIT -

API Function

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{

    public DocModel Get(string docId, string docName, string docLibrary, string newDocLibrary)
    {
        DocModel document = new DocModel();

        try
        {
            string siteurl = "http://win-n1ni65gppp2/";
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {}

    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            document.Message = ex.ToString() + "Perdistes";
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        return document;
    }

}
```

Exception Message while application is on Any CPU

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CheckFrameworkAndProcess() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_RegistryConnectionString() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Local() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_Local() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) at SPDocumentAPI.Controllers.DocumentController.Get(String docId, String docName, String docLibrary, String newDocLibrary)

Error Message when application is built under x64 platform in application properties

> Could not load file or assembly 'SPDocumentAPI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Stack Trace

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'SPDocumentAPI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
>      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'SPDocumentAPI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'SPDocumentAPI' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: That's server-side code and SharePoint is a 64-bit application. Did you add the server-side libraries to your application? If you did, your application **must** be 64-bit and located on the same servers as Sharepoint

Comment: Yeah, My Server is 64 bits, Sharepoint 2013 is 64 bits, Visual Studio 2012 version is 64 bit, I am developing on the same server. As for Libraries I am only using Microsoft.Sharepoint.

Comment: It's the *web application* that must be 64-bit, because Microsoft.SharePoint is a server-side library. Where is the code and what are the compilation/runtime errors?

Comment: The web application is running on Any CPU but the Prefer 32bit is not checked. If I set the application on 64bit do not open at all. I will post the exception message and stack trace on the main post

Comment: And what is SPDocumentAPI? SharePoint has no such library and any third-party libraries would be compiled as x64 anyway. If it's another project in your solution, it has to be set to x64 as well

Comment: Sorry SPDocumentAPI is the project name. I am running the code on a project named SPDocumentAPI

Comment: If SPDocumentAPI is the name of your MVC project, you probably need to clean the entire solution because IIS is loading a 32-bit dll somewhere. The error is specific: either SPDocumentAPI or one of the libraries it references is 32-bit

Comment: Thanks. I have cleaned the project but no luck. I will be verifying the libraries so I can check them out of the project.

Comment: I created a new mvc4 project and build it as a x64 platform target, I got Error Message when application is built under x64 platform in application properties error

Comment: Nothing works. I just want to be able to create a new word document from a existing word template using a custom web part I created for sharepoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the project was running on IIS Express and it seems that IIS Express does not compile 64bit applications on Visual Studio 2012.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process) that explains how to add some changes to the registry.

In the end just run the following code on the command prompt and restart the server.

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```