# Unity Di container not working with 64 bit build

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

I am using Unity for in WCF service to load component.

I am referring below mention article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725(v=vs.100).aspx

Service is working fine when i build service in visual studio with build option option any CPU.

As one third party component required 64 bit specific build. So i selected 64 bit build option.

I have downloaded Unity code and build for 64 bit but it is also not working.

I am getting below mention exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Unity' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.


 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Unity' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Common.Unity' could not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is not issue of Unity. 
It is issue of IISExprees of VS2012 which is support on 32 bit.

[Can't get IIS Express 8 beta to run website as 64-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process/17539364)

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3254745-allow-for-iis-express-64-bit-to-run-from-visual-st