# Machine config is loading from Framework folder instead if Framework64 folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, machine.config

All my projects had the platform x86. Now the client want us to change the platform to x64. So i have changed the active platform to x64.

Question

1) All projects platform version is not changed to x64 instead it changed to "Any CPU" ?

2) After changing the platform i am getting the BadImage format issue. What i suspect is machine config is loading from Framework folder instead if Framework64 folder.

Below is the image for the same -

[image]

Please help !!!

Comment: Can you try to execute dumpbin command to check each of your compiled DLL be x86 or x64: dumpbin /headers mydll.dll? You need to ensure each of your DLL is x64, mix x86 and x64 DLLs definitely will throw error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get IIS Express 8 beta to run website as 64-bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is a 32 bit process, so by default it launches the web site using 32 bit IIS Express. Then of course the web app on it attempts to load the 32 bit config files.

To switch to 64 bit IIS Express, you can follow this blog post,

[Can't get IIS Express 8 beta to run website as 64-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process/17539364)