# Hosting web service on IIS 7.5 which consumes 64 bit third party DLL throws error Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, iis-7.5

we are working on windows 2008 R2.
we have a web service(frame work 4.0) which consumes 64 bit third party DLL. when we run web service from VS 2013 or from IIS 7.5 we got a error saying “Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.”

with the help of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202047/cant-get-iis-express-8-beta-to-run-website-as-64-bit-process/17539364) we have set the below option in VS 2013

> Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Web Projects | Use the 64
>   bit version of IIS Express

and published the same from VS 2013 on IIS 7.5 and it is working :)

now we have published same web service on different machine where Visual studio 2013 is not there and we are getting the same problem again.

> “Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.”

how to make this web service working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of googling i have come across this link [debugging-assembly-loading-failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/debugging-assembly-loading-failures/)

so with ref to above link if i have fuslogvw.exe, it's easy to find where the problem is.
So to get fuslogvw.exe i have installed [SDK for .net framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442)

Now i got fuslogvw.exe and i configured it as mentioned in [debugging-assembly-loading-failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/debugging-assembly-loading-failures/) and i browse my web service from IIS Manager and i am expecting errors so i am checking Fusion log and i found no errors there. Confused!!!

now i came back to browser and i found my web service is working :)

So installing SDK fixed the problem.