# How do I know if <Use64BitIISExpress /> is necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms, iis-express

I have added Aspnet.MVC package in my project.
This was added in csproj file

```
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
```

It works but when I removed it, it still works.
How do I know if it is necessary? I don't want it to crash when app runs in other environments and just want to make sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's purpose of <Use64BitIISExpress /> element in csproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837683/whats-purpose-of-use64bitiisexpress-element-in-csproj-file)

Comment: @fmansour not really. I read that and it says what purpose does this have but not why was it added if it could work without it

Comment: Your project just happens to work with 32 bit and 64 bit IIS Express. But you still need to pay attention to bitness whenever you deploy such apps onto IIS or IIS Express.